# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'quantity') in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an issue where it doesn't recognize the value of array, it will triggered the error when I've only selected one or two item and click `get all` buttton , and it will says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'quantity')`  but if I selected all items there is no error, I tried declaring empty array but it doesn't work like this. Did I miss something?

**what I tried declaring an empty value**

```
let ar1 = [];
let ar2 = [];
let quantity = 0;
```

```js
$("#allcb").change(function() {
  $('tbody tr td input[type="checkbox"]').prop(
    "checked",
    $(this).prop("checked")
  );
});

$(document).on("keyup", ".quantity_input", function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
  var value_input = 0;
  var price_value = 0;
  var total_value = 0;

  value_input = $(".quantity_input", $row).val();
  price_value = $(".price_value", $row).html();
  total_value = parseInt(value_input) * parseInt(price_value);
  $(".total_value_row", $row).text(total_value);
});

$(document).on("click", ".remove_data", function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
  var checkboxName = $row.data('for');
  var $checkbox = $(`input[type="checkbox"][name="${checkboxName}"]`);
  
  $row.remove();
  $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
  $checkbox.get(0).hasCovered = false;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_data").click(function() {
    var grid = document.getElementById("Table1");

    var checkBoxes = grid.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    var str = ''

    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
      if (
        checkBoxes[i].checked &&
        checkBoxes[i].name !== "allcb" &&
        !checkBoxes[i].hasCovered
      ) {
        var row = checkBoxes[i].parentNode.parentNode;
        str +=
          '<div class="row" data-for="' + checkBoxes[i].id + '"><div class="col-md-8"><p class="me-3"> ' +
          '<a href="#" class="text-body">' +
          '<button type="button" class = "remove_data" id="remove_data">Remove item</button></a>&nbsp' +

          '<span>Quantity</span>&nbsp' +
          row.cells[2].innerHTML +
          "</a></p> " +
          '<span class="me-1">Price </span>&nbsp' +
          '<span class="me-1 price_value">' +
          row.cells[1].innerHTML +
          "</span>&nbsp" +
          '<input type="number" id="quantity_input" class="form-control form-control-sm w-px-75 quantity_input" value="1" min="1" max="5"/>&nbsp' +
          '<span class= "total_value_row" >total value is</span> ' +
          "</div><hr></div>";
        checkBoxes[i].hasCovered = true;
      }
    }
    $(".whole-div-class").append(str);
  });


  $("#get_data").click(function() {
    let ar1 = $('input[class=checkni]').map((i, el) => ({id: el.id.slice(2)})).get();
    let ar2 = $('.quantity_input').map((i, el) => ({quantity: el.value})).get();

    if (ar1 == undefined || ar2 ==undefined) {
      alert("one");
    }

    const ar3 = $('input[class=checkni]').map((i, el) => ({id: el.id.slice(2), quantity: el.value})).get();
    var merge = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++){
      let obj = {id: ar1[i]['id'], quantity: ar2[i]['quantity']};
      merge.push(obj);
    } 

    console.log(merge);


  });


});
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table border="1" id="Table1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <input type="checkbox" id="allcb" name="allcb" />
          </th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <td>Quantity</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkni" id="cb1" name="cb1" />
          </td>
          <td>200</td>
          <td> 25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkni" id="cb2" name="cb2" />
          </td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkni" id="cb3" name="cb3" />
          </td>
          <td>400</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="add_data">Add datas</button>
    <button type="button" id="get_data">Get all</button>
    
    <ul class="list-group mb-3 row whole-div-class"></ul>
```

Comment: The `for` loop is looping over the indexes of `ar1`, but you use `ar2[i]['quantity']`. If `ar1` is longer than `ar2`, then `ar2[i]` will be `undefined`

Comment: @Barmar Yes I see that, it is the best way to solve it by using condition?

Comment: You could use optional chaining: `ar2[i]?.quantity`

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function calcTotal(p, q) {
    p = parseInt(p) || 0;
    q = parseInt(q) || 0;
    return p * q;
  }

  $("#allcb").change(function() {
    $('#Table1 tbody input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
  });

  $(document).on("keyup change", ".quantity_input", function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
    $(".total_value_row", $row).text(calcTotal($(".price_value", $row).text(), $(".quantity_input", $row).val()));
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".remove_data", function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
    var checkboxName = $row.data('for');
    var $checkbox = $(`input[type="checkbox"][name="${checkboxName}"]`);

    $row.remove();
    $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
    $checkbox.get(0).hasCovered = false;
  });

  $("#add_data").click(function() {
    var grid = $("#Table1 > tbody");
    $("input:checked", grid).each(function(i, el) {
      var str = '';
      if (!el.hasCovered) {
        var row = el.closest("tr");
        str +=
          '<div class="row" data-for="' + el.id + '"><div class="col-md-8"><p class="me-3"> ' +
          '<a href="#" class="text-body">' +
          '<button type="button" class="remove_data" id="remove_data">Remove item</button></a>&nbsp' +
          '<span>Quantity</span>&nbsp' +
          $("td:eq(2)", row).html() +
          "</a></p> " +
          '<span class="me-1">Price </span>&nbsp' +
          '<span class="me-1 price_value">' +
          $("td:eq(1)", row).html() +
          "</span>&nbsp" +
          '<input type="number" id="quantity_input" class="form-control form-control-sm w-px-75 quantity_input" value="1" min="1" max="5"/> total value is ' +
          '<span class= "total_value_row" >0</span> ' +
          "</div><hr></div>";
        el.hasCovered = true;
      }
      $(".whole-div-class").append(str);
    });

    $("#get_data").click(function() {
      var ar1 = $('.checkni:checked').map(function() {
        return {
          id: this.id.slice(2)
        }
      }).get();
      var ar2 = $('.quantity_input').map(function() {
        return {
          quantity: this.value
        }
      }).get();

      if ((ar1 == undefined || ar2 == undefined) || ar1.length != ar2.length) {
        console.log("Mismatch", ar1, ar2);
      } else {

        const ar3 = $('input[class=checkni]').map(function() {
          return {
            id: this.id.slice(2),
            quantity: this.value
          }
        }).get();

        var merge = [];
        $.each(ar1, function(i, el) {
          merge.push({
            id: ar1[i].id,
            quantity: ar2[i].quantity
          });
          console.log(merge);
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="Table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox" id="allcb" name="allcb" />
      </th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <td>Quantity</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkni" id="cb1" name="cb1" />
      </td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkni" id="cb2" name="cb2" />
      </td>
      <td>300</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkni" id="cb3" name="cb3" />
      </td>
      <td>400</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<button type="button" id="add_data">Add datas</button>
<button type="button" id="get_data">Get all</button>

<ul class="list-group mb-3 row whole-div-class"></ul>
```

There are a lot of ways your code could be improved.